# Evaluating algorithm complexity of a sorting algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, big-o

Can someone help me finding the big O notation for this sorting method, is this O(n), O( n log n) or O(n^2) ?

```
for (int i = 1; i < peopleList.size(); i++) {
        for (int j = i; j > 0; j--) {
            Person lower = peopleList.get(j - 1);
            Person higher = peopleList.get(j);

            if (higher.name.compareTo(lower.name) < 0) {
                peopleList.set(j, lower);
                peopleList.set(j - 1, higher);
            } else
                break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: `O(n^2)`. Outer loop is `n` inner loop is `n/2` average.

Comment: This is an [insertion sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort).

Comment: So if the list is already sorted it is O(n), otherwise it is O(n^2)?

Comment: What have **YOU** tried so far?

Comment: To get an idea you can simply time the algorithm for some inputs of different length. Draw a graph and you'll get a pretty good idea whether it is  linear (O(n) ) or quadratic ( O(n²) ) or O(n log n)

Answer (score 0):

Say`n = peopleList.size()`. In above code, for each element in list `peopleList` at position - `i`, we are iterating over `i` elements using another loop and doing constant calculations. So, overall we are performing almost `1 + 2+ 3 + ... + n = n * (n + 1) /2` operations. Hence, time complexity of above program is `O(n^2)`.

Answer (score 0):

When evaluating Big O of an algorithm, start from the inner-most block, evaluate its complexity, and move out.

```
for (int i = 1; i < peopleList.size(); i++) {  // Will always iterate through the entire list (O(n))
        for (int j = i; j > 0; j--) {  // Best case, this iterates once per outter loop (constant), worst case iterates n times (O(n))
            Person lower = peopleList.get(j - 1);  //constant operation (assuming ArrayList)
            Person higher = peopleList.get(j);  //constant operation (assuming ArrayList)

            if (higher.name.compareTo(lower.name) < 0) {  //constant operation
                peopleList.set(j, lower);  //constant operation
                peopleList.set(j - 1, higher);  //constant operation
            } else {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then you multiply the complexity of all the layers of loops. And you get a Best case of O(n) and a worst case of O(n^2)